# Acumatica: initialize view one time only to improve performance or user experience

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I have a simple view:

```
public PXSelect<MPEmployeeTermination, Where<MPEmployeeTermination.employeeID,
        Equal<Current<TerminationFilter.employeeID>>,
        And<MPEmployeeTermination.payRunID, Equal<Current<TerminationFilter.payRunID>>>>> EmployeeTerminations;
```

and the method that initializes it:

```
public IEnumerable employeeTerminations()
    {
       return _terminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments); 
    }
```

The method `GetEmployeeTerminations` (returns `IEnumerable` ) is heavy and runs to often - any single operation in this UI. I cannot find any control when this method is called, whereas the method `GetEmployeeTerminations` can be called only one time in initialization (when constructor is called).
I can use Boolean static field to run the method one time, but I believe that exist other recommended by Acumatica patterns like attributes, etc. It is possible to set `EmployeeTerminations = GetEmployeeTerminations`, but it is unclear how to convert `IEnumerable` to `PXSelect<MPEmployeeTermination>`.
How can I do that in appropriate Acumatica pattern or do exist better patter than just static field?

UI:
[image]

[image]

I will be grateful to any advice or suggestion.

**I'm updating my question**:

The constructor is calling each time when any editable property on the UI is changed. Solution with static boolean doesn't work because, when I open and close the UI the static field is already saved. If the field is not static - it will be reset each time when constructor runs, consequently, this also will not work.

This method

```
_terminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments)
```

calculate values for "master" DAC `MPEmployeeTermination` and also for "details" DAC `MPEmployeeTerminationItem`. DAC `MPEmployeeTerminationItem` is responsible for 2 data grids in the wizard and calculate data in both DACs, communicates with remote server etc.
Sometimes it works faster, sometimes slower, but subjective user's time feels too slow:
[image]
[image]

And always at the end of the sequence we have mysterious tread.sleep that takes longer then our operation and happens behind the Acumatica scene:
[image]
I believe that recommendation is too run this method only one time in loading. What is the best place to do it? Even constructor runs here when every property on DAC is changed.

Another heavy method is called in event `MPEmployeeTermination_TerminationDate_FieldUpdated` and cannot be moved to another place and must run all calculation when this date has changed.

The main idea is too improve user experience and prevent moment than UI is stuck.
Maybe I can use asynchronous programming?

For instance if I change the method to

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable> employeeTerminations()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => _terminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments));
    }
```

UI is not stuck anymore, but I'm not sure about all possible side effects on Acumatica framework. And it event such MPEmployeeTermination_TerminationDate_FieldUpdated due to Acumatica limitation.

Comment: Could you please clarify, why do you need employeeTerminations() delegate here (add its code if possible)? You should also understand that the delegate is not about initialization! and you should use it carefully when not possible to declare some complex conditions via view declaration. Normally, when you have PXSelect declaration inside your delegate - it will read from the database only once during the first call, further selected data will be cached and got during other calls. This way performance will be good enough and no matter how heavy your BQL is.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, Evgeny. I will extend my question in respect to your respond.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really wanna run this method only one time in loading - you should do the following

1. Add a new **static** flag - `Initialized` for example
2. Rewrite `PXCancel` action (to catch an event when entity keys have been changed) and drop your flag there
3. Rewrite `PXFirst`, `PXPrevious`, `PXNext`, `PXLast` actions (to catch all navigation events) and drop your flag there
4. Use `Initialized` flag to run the needed method only once

see code below (I've taken Customers screen as an example)

```
private static bool Initialized = false;

public PXCancel<Customer> cancel;
public PXFirst<Customer> first;
public PXPrevious<Customer> prev;
public PXNext<Customer> next;
public PXLast<Customer> last;

[PXCancelButton]
protected new virtual IEnumerable Cancel(PXAdapter a)
{
    Initialized = false;
    foreach (Customer record in new PXCancel<Customer>(this, "Cancel").Press(a))
        yield return record;
}

[PXFirstButton]
protected new virtual IEnumerable First(PXAdapter a)
{
    Initialized = false;
    foreach (Customer record in new PXFirst<Customer>(this, "First").Press(a))
        yield return record;
}

[PXPreviousButton]
protected new virtual IEnumerable Prev(PXAdapter a)
{
    Initialized = false;
    foreach (Customer record in new PXPrevious<Customer>(this, "Prev").Press(a))
    {
        return BAccount.Cache.GetStatus(record) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted
            ? last.Press(a)
            : new object[] { record };
    }

    return new object[0];
}

[PXNextButton]
protected new virtual IEnumerable Next(PXAdapter a)
{
    Initialized = false;
    foreach (Customer record in new PXNext<Customer>(this, "Next").Press(a))
    {
        return BAccount.Cache.GetStatus(record) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted
            ? first.Press(a)
            : new object[] { record };
    }

    return new object[0];
}

[PXLastButton]
protected new virtual IEnumerable Last(PXAdapter a)
{
    Initialized = false;
    foreach (Customer record in new PXLast<Customer>(this, "Last").Press(a))
        yield return record;
}
```

I've tested such approach with `CustomerMaint.billContact` delegate - works fine on my instance

```
private static IEnumerable contactCurrent;

[Api.Export.PXOptimizationBehavior(IgnoreBqlDelegate = true)]
protected virtual IEnumerable billContact()
{
    if (!Initialized)
    {
        Initialized = true;

        Contact cnt = null;
        Customer customer = this.BAccount.Current;
        if (customer != null && customer.DefBillContactID != null)
        {
            cnt = FindContact(customer.DefBillContactID);
            if (cnt != null)
            {
                if (customer.IsBillContSameAsMain == true)
                {
                    cnt = PXCache<Contact>.CreateCopy(cnt);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(this.BillContact.Cache, cnt, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(this.BillContact.Cache, cnt, true);
                }
            }
        }
        return contactCurrent = new Contact[] { cnt };
    }

    return contactCurrent;
}
```

and your method will be like this

```
private static IEnumerable employeeTerminationsCurrent;

public IEnumerable employeeTerminations(PXAdapter a)
{
    if (!Initialized)
    {
        Initialized = true;
        return employeeTerminationsCurrent = _terminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments);
    }

    return employeeTerminationsCurrent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried to work with a boolean flag, however, the framework calls to the constructor of the graph every single time when I do any action in the UI. For instance, when I change the "reason" or I add a record to the data grid, the graph is created again and as a result all flags and properties reset.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Sure there are should be static fields to keep the data outside the graph constructor. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! 
What is the difference when you use private static IEnumerable employeeTerminationsCurrent; as a staic?
What are all of these buttons PXCancelButton, PXFirstButton, PXPreviousButton, PXNextButton, PXLastButton?

Comment: static field won't be rewriten during the class recriation and its ctor call. As I said, you need these events to catch all navigation events - this is the same as if entity keys changed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the screen you shared, so I will need to stick to a more general response and hope it gives you enough to get over your hurdle until someone else can provide a better answer.  I am a little concerned about the way your filter is embedded in your tab, but I'm not really familiar with building that sort of screen structure.  My screens are simple enough that my filters always live in the top section.

As you noted, you are defining a constructor for your view.  You will find many examples in Acumatica standard code where a view is controlled via a constructor.  As you are doing, a constructor may be used to limit results retrieved as per some user selectable options on the screen.  That points me to an example in PO.POCreate for the constructors on "filter" and "fixedDemand".  These populate their respective views, and fixedDemand has some applicable nuggets to how to interpret the IEnumerable.

The returned object of type IEnumerable on a constructor for a view is the view's structure in a PXResultSet for the defined PXSelect.  You can navigate the values by unboxing the PXResultset as seen in EnumerateAndPrepareFixedDemands.

```
public virtual IEnumerable EnumerateAndPrepareFixedDemands(PXResultset<POFixedDemand> fixedDemands)
{
    foreach (PXResult<POFixedDemand, InventoryItem, Vendor, POVendorInventory> rec in fixedDemands)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In your case, I believe the IEnumerable would be treated as:

```
PXResultset<MPEmployeeTermination>
```

Assuming that the structure of your screen is not causing undue overhead (again, I'm not familiar with that screen design)...

Generally speaking, if you are having performance issues then you might review whether your code is making proper use of indices and if you can narrow down the selection range.  The only time you *should* have a real performance hit would be when the result set returned is simply too large to be managed in memory.  Sometimes the fix is to add an index, and sometimes reviewing the indices tells me that I've missed a key field in my PXSelect.  You might consider Request Profiler on the menu to log the SQL commands that are being executed and try running them manually against the database to check performance and if the results are narrowed as tightly as desired.  In the very least, you might be surprised by what values are being passed into the SQL commands being sent to the database.  (That's what I usually learn from the logged SQL commands.)

Hope this helps.  Please update if you find something else for the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but deeper investigation of my problem said that this conversion will not help me. I need to analyze my problem from another angle.

Answer (score 0):

I see those approaches with help of caching mechanisms of Acumatica:

1. Implement IPrefetchable and cache your values with help of PXDataBaseSlot . [Here](http://blog.zaletskyy.com/simplest-cachinng-explanation) is one example description. And [another](https://www.acumatica.com/blog/application-wide-caching-with-slots-and-iprefetchable/) one.
2. You PXContext and slots. Here is [description](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=7d60ac9e-ff6c-40fc-a593-52e1545493fe#Section1ctl00_phDS_form_edContent) as well.
3. Use Cache.Insert which may help you to store data between calls. It may look like this:

   ```
   public PXSelect<MPEmployeeTermination, Where<MPEmployeeTermination.employeeID,
   Equal<Current<TerminationFilter.employeeID>>,
   And<MPEmployeeTermination.payRunID, Equal<Current<TerminationFilter.payRunID>>>>> EmployeeTerminations;

   public IEnumerable employeeTerminations()
   {
      bool anyFound = false;
      foreach(var row in EmployeeTerminations.Cache.Inserted)
      {
         anyFound = true;
         yield return row;
      }

     if(!anyFound)
     {
        var rows = _terminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments);
        foreach(var row in rows)
        {
           var insertedRow = EmployeeTerminations.Insert(row);
           yield return insertedRow;
        }
     }
   ```

In case of third option records also will be persisted in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all, guys, for your time and efforts.
I've tried offered solutions and nothing worked properly due to complexity of the feature I need to improve. 
The improvement of the user experience has been done by reducing of calling of the heavy function:

```
_terminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments);
```

Means, I removed view delegate override:

```
 public IEnumerable employeeTerminations()
        {
            return TerminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments);
        }
```

Instead of this method, that is called every time when every property of `EmployeeTerminations` is changed, I call it when property `TerminationDate` is changed:

```
 public virtual void MPEmployeeTermination_TerminationDate_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as MPEmployeeTermination;
        if (row.IsNull()) return;
        TerminationHandler.GetEmployeeTerminations(EmployeeTerminations, EmployeeTerminationItems, OtherTerminationPayments);

    }
```

So, instead of struggling with the infrastructure, I improved the BL and in 90% of the cases user experience improved.
Hope it will help to somebody in similar situation.